# Why is an empty hash added to every question after loading?

Tags: support, bug

I'm facing an annoying error on SO. When I click on any question, the question will be loaded and immediately an empty hash tag is added. So I need to go back twice when I want to go back to the last page.

Here is an example (random question):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783069/ns-3-[...]-interworking
```

then I will be redirected to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783069/ns-3-[...]-interworking#
```

I'm using noscript but I allowing all domains now.

Comment: Closing as dup, just so all the info is in one place. Thanks for reporting it. What browser are you using, for comparison?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 19.0.2 (Windows 7 x64) and right now updating.